# PostgreSQL - golang programs cause strange locks

Tags: go, postgresql-11

We are lately experiencing very strange locks on PostgreSQL 11.7 when we process ETL tasks using our programs in Go 1.13.8 using standard libraries sql and pq.

ETL task has to rename tables but PostgreSQL shows that this simple operation waits for Lock on relation and select from PG wiki (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) which should show blocking process shows that command "alter table .... rename to ...." is blocked by process "COPY .... to stdout" but from completely different table.

UPDATE: I modified query from PG wiki and it showed that blocking session is actually active for ~12 hours although recent COPY command runs only for a few minutes and is from completely different ETL task.

Is it possible that golang library does not close session properly and reuses it in completely different run of different ETL task? Although I do defer db.close() everywhere...

And from time to time even selects from some tables seem to by blocked by copy commands running on other tables. This is shown by the same select from PG wiki for blocking queries.

All this stuff runs from golang programs. So maybe problem is not on PostgreSQL but in golang libraries?

Comment: Is it possible that the transaction that runs the COPY statement previously touched the table you are trying to rename, but hasn't committed yet?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name complete commands are irrelevant in this case. Trust me. But you are most likely right with your second comment. I modified select from showing locks and blocking session runs for ~12 hours already. I will update question.

Comment: Your update definitely sounds like you are not ending your transactions properly. There is no need to physically close the connections, but you need to make sure your transactions are either comitted or rolled back. Check the view `pg_stat_activity` for any sessions that are `idle in transaction`